# tryCatch in R: returning what was computed in the try block when there is a warning

Tags: r, try-catch

```
y <- tryCatch({ long_calculation(x) },
               error=function(err){
                 return(NULL)
               },
               warning=function(warn){
                 # how can I return the value of long_calculation(x)
                 # without recomputing?
                 return(long_calculation(x))
               })
```

So in the try block, it does a computation that takes a long time.
In the warning block, I still want to return what was computed without recomputing it. How do I do that?

reproducible example:

```
x <- 1:10000000
x2 <- seq_len(length(x)/17)

y <- tryCatch({ sum(x/x2) },
              error=function(err){
                return(NULL)
              },
              warning=function(warn){
                # how can I return the value of long_calculation(x)
                # without recomputing?
                return(sum(x/x2))
              })
```

EDITED:

So my goal is to be able to capture the warning message, which is why I need to have the "warning" parameter assigned a function.

Comment: Hum. Can you make your example reproducible?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik i added something. not sure if it is reproducible since i can't think any situation where sum would give a warning

Comment: I have made `sum(x/x2)` give a warning. (It's `/` that gives the warning, not `sum`).

Comment: I think you will have to work on your function, not `tryCatch`, to return partial result (assuming I understand correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let the warning message appear, just skip the warning function argument to tryCatch.

```
x <- c(1:10000000)
y <- tryCatch({
  warning("Warning!")
  sum(x)
}, error = function(err) return(NULL))
```

If you want to suppress the warning message, you can use suppressWarnings.

```
x <- c(1:10000000)
y <- tryCatch(suppressWarnings({
  warning("Warning!")
  sum(x)
}), error = function(err) return(NULL))
```

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to do is to be able to capture the warning message. So that's why I need to have the warning parameter assigned a value. And then I still want to return what was computed... without recomputing it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just a matter of simplifying the code by removing any reference to warnings?

```
long_calculation <- function(x){
  x2 <- seq_len(length(x)/17)
  sum(x/x2)  
}

x <- 1:10000000

y <- tryCatch({ long_calculation(x) },
              error = function(err) NULL
              )
#Warning message:
#In x/x2 :
#  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

y
#[1] 1141800633
```

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to do is to be able to capture the warning message. So that's why I need to have the warning parameter assigned a value. And then I still want to return what was computed... without recomputing it.